# Passing item from Automator to AppleScript in a workflow

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a Automator workflow that ask:

"Ask for finder items"
"Run Apple Script"

The problem is that I can't get the items that were selected to be used in my Apple Script.

```
    set display_text to "Please enter your password:"
repeat
    considering case
        set init_pass to text returned of (display dialog display_text default answer "" with hidden answer)
        set final_pass to text returned of (display dialog "Please verify your password below." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 default answer "" with hidden answer)
        if (final_pass = init_pass) then
            exit repeat
        else
            set display_text to "Mismatching passwords, please try again"
        end if
    end considering
end repeat

tell application "Finder"
    #set theItems to choose folder with prompt "Please select a document to process:"
    #set theItems to selected
    set theItem to selection # This is where the problem is.
    set theItem to (item 1 of theItems) as alias
    set itemPath to quoted form of POSIX path of theItem
    set fileName to name of theItem
    set theFolder to POSIX path of (container of theItem as alias)
    set zipFile to quoted form of (fileName & ".zip")
    do shell script "cd '" & theFolder & "'; zip -x .DS_Store -r0 -P '" & final_pass & "' " & zipFile & " ./'" & fileName & "'"
end tell
```

Comment: My bad, I was trying different things throughout the day.  I updated the full apple script snippet.  But basically just want the selected item to be used in the AS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the `Run AppleScript` action, you'll notice if comes with some default code, starting with `on run {input, parameters}`. `Input` is a variable that contains the results of the last action: in this case, the `Get Selected Finder Items` returns a list of aliases, so you can access them like so:

[image: automator screenshot]

Easy peasy...